# Can SAML do Authorization?

Tags: authorization, saml-2.0

I know that SAML can be used for user Authentication, but what about the permission levels a user has? Can it also be used for Authorization as well? 
If not, what are the best alternatives for Open Source Authorization software?

Answer (score 12):

SAML is a protocol that can be used for exchange of any information, including authorization-related "stuff". For example, in a very simple role-based access control scenario a SAML assertion issued by the identity provider can contain user's roles represented as attributes (or a single multi-valued attribute). The service provider can then extract the roles and use them to authorize access to some resource(s).

XACML is another protocol that is specifically geared to deal with some aspects of access control in an interoperable and declarative fashion. It is rarely used and it is considerably less popular than SAML.

oAuth is often used for authorization of access, especially in the REST world with APIs.

Both oAuth and XACML can coexist with SAML or be used independently.

Answer (score 9):

SAML does not do authorization explicitly. It simply provides the attributes in the SAML token and it's up to the application as to how these are handled.

The same is true for WS-Federation.

For OAuth2, the "attributes" it provides are somewhat limited. And you still have to authenticate e.g. OpenID Connect.